# Run .jar file, but stop in first form

Tags: java, netbeans

I Using:

**NetBeans:** IDE 7.4 
**Java :** jdk1.7.0_51
**javax.swing** and **RXTXcomm** for my **RFID**

When i try to run **.jar** file, the program can running,
First form is login form, after i input username and password then click Login,
after that remain in the login form, which should be changed to the form menu.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this your code?

Comment: yes. this is my own project

Comment: Add some code. The tag says Java but people here won't know for sure what all things you are using(Java Swing  or Java is for server side and your problem is related to JavaScript). Be a little more descriptive in your problem statement which will help you get the answers.